# Image download from firebase storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to download an image file from firebase storage. But when I am clicking on download button it gives me an error that "failed to download the file from http://myimagedownloadlink"

This is my download button code

```
        downloadbtn=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.downloadbutton);
        downloadbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                Log.v(TAG, " download button click=" + path);
                //path contain download url link
                // "Myimages/images/" + mFileUri.getLastPathSegment();

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyDownloadService.class);
                intent.setAction(MyDownloadService.ACTION_DOWNLOAD);
                intent.putExtra(MyDownloadService.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_PATH, path);
                startService(intent);

                //Show loading spinner
                showProgressDialog();
            }
        });
```

My logcat is below

```
08-06 20:33:59.640 20806-20806/com.example.firebase.storage V/MyActivity:  on click method execute =https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/android-start-654f1.appspot.com/o/Myimages%2Fimages%2F10469?alt=media&token=47b6b8dc-f0aa-4413-a73f-06c1aab36a07
08-06 20:34:02.513 20806-20806/com.example.firebase.storage V/MainActivity:  download button click=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/android-start-654f1.appspot.com/o/Myimages%2Fimages%2F10469?alt=media&token=47b6b8dc-f0aa-4413-a73f-06c1aab36a07
08-06 20:34:02.984 20806-20806/com.example.firebase.storage D/Storage#DownloadService: onStartCommand:Intent { act=action_download cmp=com.example.firebase.storage/.MyDownloadService (has extras) }:1
08-06 20:34:02.984 20806-20806/com.example.firebase.storage D/Storage#DownloadService: action_download:https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/android-start-654f1.appspot.com/o/Myimages%2Fimages%2F10469?alt=media&token=47b6b8dc-f0aa-4413-a73f-06c1aab36a07
08-06 20:34:02.984 20806-20806/com.example.firebase.storage D/Storage#DownloadService: changeNumberOfTasks:0:1
08-06 20:34:03.034 20806-22421/com.example.firebase.storage I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.firebasestorage:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.firebasestorage:1
08-06 20:34:03.044 20806-22421/com.example.firebase.storage I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.firebasestorage, version >= 1
08-06 20:34:06.027 20806-22421/com.example.firebase.storage E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
                                                                                            Object does not exist at location.
                                                                                             Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404
08-06 20:34:06.067 20806-20806/com.example.firebase.storage W/Storage#DownloadService: download:FAILURE
   com.google.firebase.storage.StorageException: Object does not exist at location.
       at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask.zzcyk(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask.zzcxy(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.zzcyg(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.storage.zze.zzcym(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.zzi(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask.run(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$5.run(Unknown Source)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
08-06 20:34:06.067 20806-20806/com.example.firebase.storage D/Storage#DownloadService: changeNumberOfTasks:1:-1
08-06 20:34:06.067 20806-20806/com.example.firebase.storage D/Storage#DownloadService: stopping
08-06 20:34:06.087 20806-20806/com.example.firebase.storage D/MainActivity: downloadReceiver:onReceive:Intent { act=action_error (has extras) }
```

Comment: Post the code that shows how you are creating the `StorageReference` for the file and the method used to get the file.

Comment: Hey @User3832773, Did you find the solution?

Comment: you can not directly download the file from firebase. use the public generated URL to download the file ( this public generated url firebase uses to upload the file over firebase storage.)